# Preserving Manifest.mf when building via sbt assembly

Tags: scala, sbt, manifest, sbt-assembly, manifest.mf

When I build my project using `sbt assembly`, I get `java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. The solution that google recommends, is to use `MergeStrategy.discard`.

That works in getting the project to build - but it crashes at runtime, because Dropwizard (a dependency) relies on info contained in manifest.mf (full issue details: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/455 ).

The recommendation when encountering that error, is to merge the manifests.

I've tried all the MergeStrategies on Manifest.MF that seem like they'd do the trick (`filterDistinctLines`, `concat`, `first`, `last`), they all cause the build to fail with `java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. The only thing that compiles is `discard`, but that causes the program to crash at runtime due to Dropwizard relying on the mf file.

Any ideas what to do here? Is there a way to merge the manifests as described in the comments at https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/455 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing this:

- Separated the Scala & Java projects
- Build the sbt project as is - copy it to the java project/lib directory
- Added a system dep for lib/scala project, and used the add-jar plugin to add this jar to the classpath when building the fatjar:

  ```
         <plugin>
              <groupId>com.googlecode.addjars-maven-plugin</groupId>
              <artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.5</version>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>add-jars</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                          <resources>
                              <resource>
                                  <directory>${real.base.dir}/lib</directory>
                              </resource>
                          </resources>
                      </configuration>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>
  ```
- Build the java project fatjar and deploy it - it now has access to the scala jar on the classpath.

Script (server is the name of the java project i made):

```
sbt clean assembly
cp target/scala*/project*.jar server/lib
cd server
mvn clean install
cd ../
cp server/target/server*.jar target
```